# How many triangles are there in each "layer" of Poincaré disk?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, algebraic-topology

[image]
Assume we grow from a single triangle layer by layer to get the whole disk. Every time a new ring of triangles makes all the vertices of the triangles already in the picture surround by seven triangles. How many triangles are there in the nth triangle? Any hint?

Currently I get 1, 15, 180.

Comment: I believe the official term for your layer/ring notion is "corona" in tiling lore. This may help you with web searches. (You may have to sift through numerous hits related to tiling graphic elements in the Corona app-creation program.)

Comment: This is a beautiful picture. I think, it is generated b reflections using (7,7,7) Coxeter group acting on the hyperbolic plane.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,15,180&sort=&language=english&go=Search) result in OEIS, the sequence you may be looking for is: $$a_n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+3)!}{48}. $$

Comment: This is not barycenteric subdivision of anything and its rate of growth I think, is only exponential, not factorial, in n, but I have to think how to prove it.

Comment: @MoisheCohen It is only exponential - there are two different classes of triangle in each layer (those edge-adjacent to the previous layer and those corner-adjacent) and you can write a pair of Fibonacci-style recurrence relations that give the number of each class in the current layer in terms of the number of each class in the previous layer; I've done something similar in the past for the pentagonal tilings. I'll see if I can work out the details and post them in a bit.